# Need to create a pipeline for parallel execution

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have 2 lookup activities with two different set of datasets and each lookup have one for each. How to run two lookup activities in parallel with in same pipeline

I have tried with two different pipelines but I want to do it in single pipeline.

Pipeline 1 for insert - Lookup1 have file1 and we have to load to cosmos using api

Pipeline 2 for update - Lookup2 have file2 and we have to update cosmos db using api

Note: we have lookup files in datalake, both file1 and file2 have different names

Comment: please add What you have tried and error you are facing,

Comment: Pratik I added some information it might be useful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your ask is but you can execute multiple activities in parallel or sequential :
[image]

Comment: I added extra information you can check. If any other inputs needed I will provide